# Keras Sequence: Specify input shape with three parameters

Tags: python, keras

I have a dataframe with the following setup:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(100, 20, 3)
```

Here there are 100 time slices, 20 observations, and 3 attributes per observation.

I am trying to figure out how to pass the data above to the following Keras sequence:

```
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Activation
import keras

# config
stateful = False
look_back = 3
lstm_cells = 1024
dropout_rate = 0.5
n_features = int(X.shape[1]*3)
input_shape = (look_back, n_features, 3)
output_shape = n_features

def loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(lstm_cells, stateful=stateful, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(output_shape, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer='sgd')
```

Running this throws:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_23: expected
>   ndim=3, found ndim=4

Does anyone know how I can reshape `X` to pass it into the model? Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to get things rolling:

```
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Activation
import keras

# config
stateful = False
look_back = 3
lstm_cells = 1024
dropout_rate = 0.5
n_features = int(X.shape[1]) * 3
input_shape = (look_back, n_features)
output_shape = n_features

def loss(y_true, y_pred):
  return keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(lstm_cells, stateful=stateful, return_sequences=True, input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_cells, stateful=stateful, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_cells, stateful=stateful))
model.add(Dense(output_shape, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer='sgd')
```

Then one can partition the training data as follows:

```
# build training data
train_x = []
train_y = []
n_time = int(X.shape[0])
n_obs = int(X.shape[1])
n_attrs = int(X.shape[2])

# note we flatten the last dimension
for i in range(look_back, n_time-1, 1):
  train_x.append( X[i-look_back:i].reshape(look_back, n_obs * n_attrs ) )
  train_y.append( X[i+1].ravel() )

train_x = np.array(train_x)
train_y = np.array(train_y)
```

Then one can train the toy model:

```
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=10)
```

Comment: Could you spell out why the three similar _add(LSTM...)_ commands are needed?

Comment: @Helen sure thing--in this case I was just trying to reimplement a neural network from the paper Chorrnn, which had multiple layers of LSTM cells. In general those multiple layers of LSTM cells seem to help learn longer sequences of data...

Comment: Ah, so, is each of these commands adding an extra layer? (I'm just confused because the original code had only one such command, so I wonder if all three commands are a needed replacement of the original single one, or if they are something additional.)

Comment: Yes, each LSTM() call adds a new layer. If you're stuck as I was, try reading up on the `return_sequences` parameter, which is important in controlling the shapes of data as it comes through the network. Check this out for more information: https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/